# How to prevent to open MS Access database file?

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, database-security

I am developing one Inventory project  to sell by using C# and MS Access.
 After sell this product, Client(or any other) may open the document and read it. I need to overcome this less secure. 
 
I googled it and found solution that Password protection. But lot of tools there to breach this.
 Finally I need to close all the ways for steal and view data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you feel that the password protection feature of the Access Database Engine (ACE) does not offer a sufficient level of security against unauthorized "snooping" of the data then you really should consider using SQL Server instead of ACE as the back-end database.